# Confused about constructors in javascript

Tags: javascript, constructor

Please excuse me if I am missing anything important or even silly. I'm trying to print the constructor's name from objects. I followed two approaches.

First approach's code is below,

```
var CF = function () {
   p1 = "";
   p2 = "";
}
var cf1 = new CF();
cf1.constructor.name
```

Output :

```
""
```

second code,

```
function CF() {
   p1 = "";
   p2 = "";
}
var cf1 = new CF();
console.log(cf1.constructor.name);
```

Output :

```
CF
```

I guess you have undertood what I wanted to say. The first `CF`'s objects constructor name is `""` where as second ones output is `CF`.

I tried to know the differnce like below

```
var CF = function() { }
typeof CF;
function CF() { };
typeof CF
```

But no luck they both output

```
"function"
```

**Why is that behavior with first approach? What is the difference?**

(I'm using chrome console)

Comment: The function expression sets an unamed function to a variable, the function has no name,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first constructor function is an anonymous function meaning it has no name.  The second constructor function has a name which allows its constructor to be printed.

Comment: Simple and precise :)

Answer (score 1):

In the first approach you just create an object named CF that contains an unnamed function that is a constructor for a class which is unknown until that point.

In the second code you write the constructor for the class in a function named CF and then use that constructor to create an instance of your class in the object named cf1.

I hope you understand what I'm trying to say, basically your first constructor has no name.

Answer (score 0):

`function CF() { };` is shorthand for `var CF = function() { }`, so typically they are the same.

That being said, `function CF() { };` gives you some benefit in debugging in node, since it allows node to give more precise feedback on what/where went wrong.